# How To Input Number To Textbox Jquery Append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to insert number to textbox but i cannot insert when i added row, how to inserted to append textbox?

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
var counter = 0;
$("#addrow").on("click", function () {
    counter = $('#myTable tr').length - 3;
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="item' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="stock' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel" value="Delete"></td>';
    newRow.append(cols);
    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    counter++;
});

$("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();

    counter -= 1
    $('#addrow').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "Add Row");
});

$('#stock').val(0);
    var nilai1 = $('#stock').val();     
    $('.angka').click(function(){
        if($('#stock').val()==0){
            nilai1 ='';
        }
        nilai1 += $(this).val();
        $('#stock').val(nilai1);
    });
});
</script>
```

Might be able to help me? for more details here [preview](https://jsfiddle.net/xh5uyjdh/)

Comment: you want to insert 1,2,3 etc in the newly added rows right ?

Comment: counter++ makes zero sense when in the start of the function you read the length

Comment: @UsmanRana yes, how to insert on added rows?

Comment: So set the value of the textbox?

Comment: @epascarello counter++ to set an array on textbox, yes that is :)

Comment: In that code, you do not use it. `counter = $('#myTable tr').length - 3`  makes the -- and ++ lines useless.

Comment: For your textbox stock is a name attribute not an ID

Comment: @Osama if i set attribute id still not insert on add rows textbox :/

Comment: Of course because it is not only stock it also came with counter according to your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select any field whether it is added dynamically or not and you're able to add values in selected text field

```js
var counter = 0;
var sItem;
$(document).on('click', '.dumy', function(){
    sItem = $(this);
    
});
    $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
        counter = $('#myTable tr').length - 3;
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        cols += '<td><input type="text" name="item' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="dumy" name="stock' + counter + '" id="stock' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel" value="Delete"></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
        counter++;
    });

    $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        
        counter -= 1
        $('#addrow').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "Add Row");
    });
    
    $('#stock').val(0);
    
  $('.angka').click(function(){
    var nilai1 = $(sItem).val();
    if($(sItem).val() == 0){
       nilai1 ='';
       }
   nilai1 += $(this).val();
   $(sItem).val(nilai1);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
     <input type="button" class="angka" value="1" id="satu">
     <input type="button" class="angka" value="2" id="dua">
     <input type="button" class="angka" value="3" id="tiga">
          </div>
<table id="myTable" class="order-list">
    <thead>
    <tr>
            <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
                <input type="button" id="addrow" value="Add Row" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Stock</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="item0" id="item" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="stock0" class="dumy" id="stock" />
            </td>
            <td><a class="deleteRow"></a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you better explain your question? It seems to me you are trying to use the [1] [2] [3] buttons to write a value in the selected textbox but instead you only get it to the first one.
If I did not misunderstand you, your problem is right in this piece of code:

```
var nilai1 = $('#stock').val();     
    $('.angka').click(function(){
        if($('#stock').val()==0){
            nilai1 ='';
        }
        nilai1 += $(this).val();
        $('#stock').val(nilai1);
```

Basically your nila1 variable is always pointing to the DOM object referred by #stock therefore you will always be writing in that specific textbox.

I wouldn't recommend using pure JQuery for doing this kind of dinamic binding, or you could at least reconsider the design of those buttons.

As soon as you'll have better explained your problem I'll try to write down a solution for you keeping this concept.

Comment: yes that is, i cannot insert button [1] [2] [3] on textbox in row what i added, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to add a value to the input when you create it like this:

```js
(function($) {
  let counter = 0;
  
  $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
    counter = $('#myTable tr').length - 3;
    const newRow = $("<tr>");
    let cols = "";
    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="item' + counter + '" /></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="stock' + counter + '" value="0" /></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel" value="Delete" /></td>';
    newRow.append(cols);
    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    counter++;
  });

  $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();

    counter -= 1
    $('#addrow').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "Add Row");
  });

  $('#stock').val(0);
  var nilai1 = $('#stock').val();  
  $('.angka').click(function(){
    if($('#stock').val()==0){
      nilai1 ='';
    }
    nilai1 += $(this).val();
    $('#stock').val(nilai1);
  });
})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
     <input type="button" class="angka" value="1" id="satu">
     <input type="button" class="angka" value="2" id="dua">
     <input type="button" class="angka" value="3" id="tiga">
          </div>
<table id="myTable" class="order-list">
    <thead>
    <tr>
            <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
                <input type="button" id="addrow" value="Add Row" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Stock</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="item0" id="item" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="stock0" id="stock" />
            </td>
            <td><a class="deleteRow"></a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: the number still insert on top text box, not on added row :/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, when i add a row '0' is displayed in the Stock textbox.

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function($) {
  let counter = 0;
  
  $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
    counter = $('#myTable tr').length - 2;
       $('#current').val(counter);
    const newRow = $("<tr>");
    let cols = "";
    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="item' + counter + '"  id="item' + counter + '"  /></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="stock' + counter + '" id="stock' + counter + '" value="0" /></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel" value="Delete" /></td>';
    newRow.append(cols);
    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    counter++;

  });

  $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();

    counter -= 1
    $('#addrow').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "Add Row");
  });

  $('#stock').val(0);
 
  $('.angka').click(function(){

  rownumber = $('#current').val();
    alert(rownumber);
  var nilai1 = $('#stock'+  rownumber ).val(); 
    if($('#stock'+rownumber).val()==0){
      nilai1 ='';
    }
    nilai1 += $(this).val();
    $('#stock'+rownumber).val(nilai1);
  });
})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
     <input type="button" class="angka" value="1" id="satu">
     <input type="button" class="angka" value="2" id="dua">
     <input type="button" class="angka" value="3" id="tiga">
          <input type="hidden" id="current" value="" />
          </div>
<table id="myTable" class="order-list">
    <thead>
    <tr>
            <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
                <input type="button" id="addrow" value="Add Row" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Stock</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="item0" id="item0" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="stock0" id="stock0" rel="0" value="0" />
            </td>
            <td><a class="deleteRow"></a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You just need to tell the click buttons which Stock field to insert the value into.

Comment: why number input insert on below text box, when i added rows :/

Comment: When you insert a new input, it should have a unique identifier. Otherwise, the Click button event will only insert on the input value with ID identifier of "#stock".